# Create New Document For Every New User

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Right now, I'm on an activity where a user has to input their first name, last name, and id into an EditText. The value they put in there is saved onto the Firestore Console. Here is my problem:

I open my app and sign in with google with my google account, let's call this account my primary account. I fill in the 3 EditTexts, and press on the save button that I named as "btnNextStep" (because it's meant to bring you to the next part of the form, but for now it is the "save" button). Once I press save, I can see the data I filled in, on Google Firestore. Now if I were to sign in to another Google account on the same device, call it my secondary account, and I fill in the EditTexts. Once I press save, instead of creating a new document in Firestore, it overwrites the primary account's data. The final product on Firestore is that it has the data from the secondary account saved, but the data from the primary account is now gone.

Here is the code to my .java file for this activity:

```
package com.example.attenda_attempt3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StudentInformationFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnNextStep;
    EditText etFirstName;
    EditText etLastName;
    EditText etSchoolID;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_information_form);

        btnNextStep = findViewById(R.id.btnNextStep);
        etFirstName = findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
        etLastName = findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
        etSchoolID = findViewById(R.id.etSchoolID);

        btnNextStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String firstName = etFirstName.getText().toString();
                String lastName = etLastName.getText().toString();
                String schoolID = etSchoolID.getText().toString();

                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("First Name", firstName);
                data.put("Last Name", lastName);
                data.put("School ID", schoolID);


                db.collection("Users").document("User Information").set(data)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occurred, Data Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Can someone help me make it so everytime a user presses the "btnNextStep", it creates a new document and saves the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to generate a unique ID for each user and enter that into this line:

```
db.collection("Users").document("uniqueUserId").set(data)
```

If you'd be using Firebase Authentication, it'd automatically generate such a unique user ID for each user. But since you're not using any existing user management API (which is fine), you'll need to generate the ID yourself, associate it with the user in the database as shown above, and possibly also store it in local storage (like `SharedPreferences`) to be able to restore it when the app restarts.

Comment: I used firebase authentication to set up the google sign in activity I made. How would I use the firebase auth in this situation?

Comment: If each user needs to write their own data, you can do `String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` to get the `uid` and then `db.collection("Users").document(uid).set(data)` to write their data to their personal document. In that case, also see this documentation on how to secure access: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access

Comment: Wow, man! It works! You really saved me so much time and it works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you!